# Creation of wiki tags

Tags: discussion, tags, wiki

At the moment we don't have wiki for tags (for example the [`osx`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/info) tag).

I know it's written a user need to have more than 1000 points to edit the tag wiki, but soon users will reach 1k points. Therefore, I think we should beginning answering these questions :

- What tags will need a wiki ?
- What do we want inside a tag wiki ?

Wikis would be nice, so users could understand the differences between `osx`, `mac` and `apple` or when to use `software-recommendation`, …

Answer (score 2):

In general, of-the-top-of-my-head fashion:

- `[osx]` would need a wiki.
- `[apple]` would need a wiki.
- `[mac]` would need a wiki.

Actually, anything that is technically a proper noun should have a wiki. `[firefox]` for example, or `[steve-jobs]` perhaps? `[iphone]`, `[ios]`, `[macbook]` should have wikis.

By no means should they be insanely comprehensive though, just a couple of lines (or paragraphs as they prefer) describing the tag and applicable uses.

Comment: For reference, `[osx]` and `[mac]` on Super User already have wiki entries we can rip wholesale. (After all I made them)

Comment: I tried to copy `[osx]` and `[mac]`. Are you ok with the result ?

Comment: @Studer: Looks great!

Comment: Answer http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/609/is-it-osx-or-os-x/620#620 under [Is it OSX or OS X?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/609/8546) discourages [osx] without a space, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

## tag wiki entry for [core-storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-storage)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/core-storage/info

Process seems fine to me.

This particular tag was discussed in chat before someone created it for me, I drafted the wiki entry, entry was approved, recently edited (to include the [lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion) tag within the body of the wiki entry) and again approved.

Answer (score 0):

## What tags will need a wiki?

Blogged today:

- [Improved Tagging — Blog — Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)

I think:

- all tags should have at least an excerpt, because the new design draws attention to gaps
- the excerpt should be not too long
- the excerpt need not be a *verbatim* excerpt from the full information; more important for the excerpt alone to help a user to decide whether a tag is appropriate.

### Room for improvement: an example

[image: Screenshot of excerpts for two tags]

In the example above:

- my current excerpt for [[core-storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/core-storage/info)] is not good enough; showing it as an *Apple thing*, with sometimes *different names*, is too **nondescript**
- there may be a generation of users to whom Corel is **unknown**.