# How to propose tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

I want to propose a synonym for a tag, how do I do? I have read that it is available to create tag synonyms for users that have 2.5k rep but I don't know from when it's possible to propose a tag synonym.

Comment: Ah, just realised that you asked about synonyms. Rules are similar though, propose them on Meta.AD first :-)

Comment: @nohillside That's what I thought when I read your comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has been written about tag creation and I strongly recommend to familiarize yourself with the discussions before proposing new tags. [Creation of wiki tags](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/creation-of-wiki-tags?rq=1) and [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug) contain a lot of valuable information about the topic, as do other questions linked there.

From the [Help Center article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) about tags:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> **As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible**, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, **you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic** that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

If, after reading up on the topic, you still find a term which should be turned into a tag, please propose its creation here on Meta first. In the post, explain why the tag brings value and provide a first proposal for both the usage guidance and the long description. We can then let the community discuss and if necessary vote on the new tag.