# FileVault 1 and 2: should we have tags [filevault-1] and [filevault-2] for the two different technologies?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

## Problem

Looking ahead: expect confusion to arise from Apple's commonplace use of one word *FileVault* — without a version number — for two **very different** technologies.

(Versions 1 and 2 both involve encryption, but encryption is applied at totally different levels.)

## Options (not mutually exclusive)

1. continue with one tag [filevault](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault) for two different technologies

   I can add the tag [core-storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-storage) to questions that relate to **FileVault 2**. Example result:

   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-storage+filevault

   If only a limited number of tags can be added to a question, this is not ideal.
2. have two tags [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) and [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) instead of the one [filevault](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault)

   I can do a little CHAOS-like housekeeping. Currently only six results to the following:

   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault
3. ????

   At the moment I can't recall the third option that came to mind, but I'll leave this question as a placeholder, to be revisited and edited very soon. Hopefully within the next twenty-four hours.
4. tag synonym [legacy-filevault](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy-filevault)

   [Starred in Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1509882#1509882).

---

Meta users: if you imagine any other options, please edit this question. Thanks :-)

### Side note

We can not *assume* version 2 where FileVault is mentioned by a user of Lion. Both versions 1 and 2 can be used simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got it right with [filevault-1] and [filevault-2].

That won't cause any confusion, and it follows our usual pattern of [product-version] (like [ios-4]).

Answer (score 1):

### Draft text for notional filevault-1 tag

What's below should appear more effective in the tag wiki than in this Q&A …

#### Excerpt

FileVault 1: encryption of a user's home directory

#### Body

In [tiger](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiger), [panther](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panther), [leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leopard) and [snow-leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-leopard):

- the interface to enable or disable [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) is in [system-preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-preferences)
- [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) is always known as *FileVault*, without a version number.

In [lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion):

- [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) and [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) can work together in harmony, without conflict
- the interface to disable [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) is in [system-preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-preferences) alongside the interface for [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2)
- [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) is sometimes known as *FileVault*, without a version number
- [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) is sometimes known as *Legacy FileVault*.

Answer (score 1):

### Draft text for notional filevault-2 tag

What's below should appear more effective in the tag wiki than in this Q&A …

#### Excerpt

FileVault 2: Apple Core Storage full disk encryption (FDE) of the startup volume

#### Body

In [lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion):

- [filevault-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-1) and [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) can work together in harmony, without conflict
- the interface to enable or disable [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) is in [system-preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-preferences)
- [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) uses [core-storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-storage)
- [filevault-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filevault-2) is usually known as *FileVault*, without a version number.