# Can we ask questions about Apple software on Windows?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Are questions using Apple OS and Apple Software (3rd party or otherwise) on non apple hardware allowed?

This is more general than [hackintosh](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-ask-different) which is also up for discussion. In this case, it might be iTunes on Windows or other services.

Should the FAQ and site-scope allow some or all of these questions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I feel that Apple software is pertinent. It runs on many devices and platforms, if you have an issue with Safari on XP that is applicable as it falls under the "Apple" umbrella.

Comment: +agreed... unless the question has more to do with windows itself than apple software

Comment: Like iTunes or QuickTime for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that issues related to something like Parellels or VMWare Fusion, running Windows on the Mac should be allowed.  But not for a purely Windows side issue, but rather for items unique to running Windows in a VM on a Mac.