# Software recommendation: Help-center information clashing with meta?

Tags: discussion

Similarly to [Discrepancy between help-center and community consensus?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2882/251859) my latest question was judged to provoke opinion based answers and therefore clashing with the "definitions for this site in the help center".

When asking for:
[How and with which free markdown editor can one write with good integration with this site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/306357/251859)

I specifically read and tried to follow: [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/251859) while phrasing this awkward question, hence the less than optimal title.

If the question in question does indeed not follow the rules according to the current community:

- are software recommendations now illegal across the board?
- are help center and/or meta in dire need of reconciliation?

Since an indeed helpful comment suggested to put this into meta:

What takes precedence: help center, meta?

Comment: Dire and clashing seem odd adjectives. Would you mind if I tried editing your post on the main site to test my potential answer ; BBEdit ?

Comment: @bmike not at all. The current state of the main Q *is* deplorable since I really lost it panicking while seeing the closevotes coming in. If the scalpel doesn't cut, use a little axe!

Comment: It might be hard to overcome a -5 vote count, but it can’t hurt. Worst case you earn a badge by deleting it and since it’s here on meta - assuming we can all agree it’s in good shape - we could probably have enough votes to counteract the initial disagree votes. It’s not my taste. Give me a couple hours to wrap up work and clear my editing brain.

Comment: @bmike Just a friendly reminder: I do not mind how many hours you need. I just wouldn't want to see the Q go under completely without trying sth first. If you think it's not worth it anymore, please elaborate in chat about BBEdit.

Comment: @bmike Just a friendly reminder: I still do not mind how many hours you need. It's just sad to see the Q go under completely without trying sth first. If you think it's not worth it anymore, please elaborate somewhere about BBEdit.

Answer (score 3):

Software recommendation questions always have been (and will be) tricky on this site, so irregardless of whether a posts tries to follow  the meta recommendation it might get downvotes and/closed. In your case it was difficult to see that you were looking for a Mac based solution (there was neither a tag nor a sentence describing this need) so I understand why others considered it off-topic. But that is something which is easily fixable. What isn‘t though are questions which look for opionon based answers, these usually get closed rather fast.

Having said that, I don‘t really see a clash between help center and meta. The meta article explains how to write good software rec questions, the help center defines basic characteristics of acceptable questions. So a question asking for Windows software or using rude language would get closed even if it follows the recommendations in the meta article.  But maybe I‘m missing some details here, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thx for your patience. I reasoned posting to Ask is obviously asking for Mac-based recs as to be redundant to include again a sentence, same as using too many tags, but 'macos' additionally read more like for the OS itself.

Comment: There is always iOS as well :-)